# Whats the difference between binary_oarchive and basic_binary_oarchive?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, binary

Cant find any discussion on this, what should I use?

Comment: Looks like one is a template and the other a type alias.

Comment: Consult your documentation; these are not standard library classes. But the usual convention in the standard library is for the prefix `basic_` to mean that the name is a template and that the name without that prefix is a particular specialization. So 'std::basic_string<Ty>` is the template that supports various character types, and `std::string` is the specialization `std::basic_string<char>`.

Comment: theres almost zero documentation on boost Archives

Comment: @Icebone1000 boost archives are part of the boost::serialization library, that's why you can't get any docs, because you are looking for the wrong name http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/libraries.htm